# Protobuf.ProtoException: No parameterless constructor found... when receiving specific message from client

Tags: c#, sockets, protobuf-net

I'm playing around with programming an asynchronous server in C#. I am using proto-buf.net to send objects between the client and server. For the most part, it was working fine until I started testing the program with another user connected to my server.

This specific problem occurs when attempting the following:

When a button is pressed, code will be called that sends a `BattleMessage` to all clients connected to the server.

```cs
// in server
var message = new BattleMessage
{
  Players = players, // List<string>
  Enemies = enemies, // List<Enemy objects>
  Current = currentPlayer, // string, the current player's name
  Boss = isBoss, // boolean
  Turns = turns // string
};
```

Upon receiving this message, the client will change GUIs to display a "battle screen" with all the information sent by the BattleMessage displayed for the user. In doing so, it will run a check to see if the client the information is being displayed for's name matches "Current."

If it does, it'll send back this message:

```cs
// still in client
            if(current.Name.Equals(Current))
            {
                var message = new CurrentPlayerBattleMessage
                {
                    Name = current.Name,
                    Defense = current.GetDefense(),
                    HP = current.Hp,
                    MP = current.Mp,
                    skills = D,
                    IsPhysical = current.IsPhysical,
                };

                message.Weaknesses = weaknesses;
                Client.SendMessage(message); // send the message back to the server
            }
```

The server will then receive the message, process it, and act accordingly:

```cs
// back in the server

                // in Receive(IAsyncResult r)
                Socket client = r.AsyncState as Socket;
                client.EndReceive(r);

                // NetMessage is abstract, CurrentPlayerBattleMessage extends it
                NetMessage message = PacketManager.ProcessMessage(buffer);
                buffer = new byte[BUFFERSIZE]; // buffer: private byte[] buffer, BUFFERLENGTH = 2048
                client.BeginReceive(buffer, 0, BUFFERSIZE, SocketFlags.None, new AsyncCallback(Receive), client);

              // process after being identified
              if(message.GetType().Equals(typeof(CurrentPlayerBattleMessage)))
              {
                    var current = message as CurrentPlayerBattleMessage;

                    BattlePlayer bp = new BattlePlayer
                    {
                        Name = current.Name,
                        Defense = current.Defense,
                        HP = current.HP,
                        MP = current.MP,
                        Skills = current.Skills,
                        IsPhysical = current.IsPhysical,
                        Weaknesses = current.Weaknesses
                    };
                    //update server GUI
                    server.AddCurrentBattlePlayer(bp);
               }
```

When only one person was connected to the server, the current player's skills and stats would be successfully loaded. When two people were connected to the server, the exception listed in the question would be thrown.

When I checked to see if the buffer was empty, since I've heard that can cause this error to appear, it actually turned out to be the case! I'm not entirely sure why, though or how to go about stopping it. For reference, the buffer is reset after a Login message is sent to it. Could this be preventing it from receiving messages?

Also, for context, here are the methods used to process messages:

```cs
        // both methods are used by the Client as well
        public static byte[] CreateMessage(NetMessage message)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                Serializer.SerializeWithLengthPrefix(stream, message, PrefixStyle.Base128);
                return stream.ToArray();
            }
        }

        public static NetMessage ProcessMessage(byte[] buffer)
        {
            using (var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                return Serializer.DeserializeWithLengthPrefix<NetMessage>(stream, PrefixStyle.Base128);
            }
        }
```

EDIT: I was asked for some class info, so here you go:

```cs
// the message causing me the issue (SERVER)
    [ProtoContract]
    public class CurrentPlayerBattleMessage : NetMessage
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public int Defense { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public int HP { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public int MP { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(5, AsReference = true)]
        public Dictionary<string, int> Skills { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(6)]
        public bool IsPhysical { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(7, AsReference = true)]
        public List<int> Weaknesses { get; set; }

        public CurrentPlayerBattleMessage() { }
    }

// (CLIENT)
    [ProtoContract]
    public class CurrentPlayerBattleMessage : NetMessage
    {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(2)]
        public int Defense { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(3)]
        public int HP { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(4)]
        public int MP { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(5, AsReference = true)]
        public Dictionary<string, int> skills { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(6)]
        public bool IsPhysical { get; set; }
        [ProtoMember(7, AsReference = true)]
        public List<int> Weaknesses { get; set; }

        public CurrentPlayerBattleMessage() { }
    }
```

```cs
// the parent class
    [ProtoContract]
    [ProtoInclude(500, typeof(LoginMessage))]
    [ProtoInclude(501, typeof(InventoryMessage))]
    [ProtoInclude(502, typeof(BattleMessage))]
    [ProtoInclude(503, typeof(CurrentPlayerBattleMessage))]
    [ProtoInclude(504, typeof(UpdateBattleMessage))]
    [ProtoInclude(505, typeof(RewardMessage))]
    [ProtoInclude(506, typeof(RetreatMessage))]
    public abstract class NetMessage
    {
        public NetMessage() { }
    }
```

Attempted solutions/ideas so far:

- Having myself and the person helping me test connect to the server individually such that I would try to see if I could get my stats to appear if I were the only person connected, then I'd restart the server, and finally the other guy would do the same. This led to the message being received by the client and the skills being received.
- Checking to see if the Client was even sending the message at all. It was, the server was just not processing it properly.

  - Checking to see if the buffer was empty, it turns out it was!

Comment: Hi; is this an inheritance scenario? Is it using [ProtoInclude] etc? Trying to understand the example...

Comment: You do not have any classes shown so I can't figure out where the constructor is located.  if the class is ABC  then all you need is public ABC() { }.  You have a constructor with one or more parameters and you just need to add a constructor with zero parameters.

Comment: I've updated the post with the classes in question. Hopefully this should answer some questions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your updates until now (tip: use @ i.e. @that'snotentirelytrue to ping folks if there are relevant updates); if the buffer is empty, then you have a `NetMessage` with no content, i.e. *just* a `NetMessage`. So: how did we get an empty buffer here? Note: it doesn't look like you're processing the return value from `EndReceive`, so this *seems* like a general "TCP framing" problem; see https://blog.marcgravell.com/2013/02/how-many-ways-can-you-mess-up-io.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by keeping track of the last message that was sent (the one that kept triggering the error) and resending it. Whenever a Protobuf Exception was thrown, the program assumes that it was due to an empty buffer.

This is not the greatest solution, in fact it's very "hacky," but it resolves the immediate problem that I had.